# How to keep or remove *all* rows by group if a condition is met anywhere in the group

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, subset

I have a data frame with column A (Sample_id), column B (Prey), and column C (Count). Column B has 3 factors: P1, P2, P3. I want to remove all Sample_id's where P3 does not occur - in other words, retain only the Sample_id's where P3 does occur.

Essentially, I want to go from this original dataset :

```
df_orig <- data.frame(Sample_id = rep(c('S1', 'S2', 'S3'), each = 3),
                   Prey = rep(c('P1', 'P2', 'P3'), times = 3),
                   Count = (c(10, 16, 0, 5, 0, 0, 6, 2, 9)))
```

to this reduced dataset:

```
df_red <- data.frame(Sample_id = rep(c('S3'), each = 3),
                   Prey = rep(c('P1', 'P2', 'P3'), times = 1),
                   Count = (c(6, 2, 9)))
```

I think I should be able to achieve this with dplyr filter somehow, but my attempts (see below) removes the prey groups P2 and P1. Rather, I need to filter where a condition is met (i.e. retain Sample_id where P3 occurs).

How do I do this?

```
library(dplyr)
df_red <- df_orig %>%
  group_by(Sample_id) %>%
  filter(Prey == "P3") %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to incorporate `Count` into your condition. And to keep all rows for a given `Sample_id` if the condition is met in any row for that `Sample_id`, wrap the condition in `any()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df_red <- df_orig %>%
  group_by(Sample_id) %>%
  filter(any(Prey == "P3" & Count > 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
  
df_red
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Sample_id Prey  Count
  <chr>     <chr> <dbl>
1 S3        P1        6
2 S3        P2        2
3 S3        P3        9
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! Is there a way to do this for when there is no 0s in the count (i.e. there is just no row for an absent prey?

Comment: I think this code should still work in that case, since the first part of the condition, `Prey == "P3"`, won’t be met. If it doesn’t work, let me know and maybe edit your post with additional data showing that test case.

Answer (score 0):

The following works to get from your original to your desired dataset:

```
df_orig %>%
   filter(Sample_id == "S3")
```

Is this all you are trying to do or is there something else you're trying to achieve?

Comment: But I have like 200 Samples; and I also need to redo this for every single prey group, so need something that does not require me to sieve through the dataset to check which samples have the prey and which don't.

Comment: Oh I see, the other answer will do that.