# Remove all variable rows if a condition is not met, otherwise, keep all rows

Tags: r, select, dplyr, filter

Example data:

```
name <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D","D")
year <- c(2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2019,2020,2021,2018,2019,2020,2021)
col <- c(2,1,5,6,7,5,7,3,7,9,1,4)

df <- cbind(name,year,col)
```

Desired output:

```
name1 <- c("C","C","C","D","D","D","D")
year1 <- c(2019,2020,2021,2018,2019,2020,2021)
col1 <- c(5,7,3,7,9,1,4)

df2<- cbind(name1,year1,col1)
```

I want to grab variables if the latest data set is available, and by extension all subsequent years.

I.e. If a variable (A, B, C, or D) contains data in the year column of 2021, keep all rows. In all other instances, delete all rows. The start year may not be the same, but they must contain the latest year.

I started off trying to pipe something with dplyr using filter and then got stumped.

Similar approaches:
[How to keep or remove *all* rows by group if a condition is met anywhere in the group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74245666/how-to-keep-or-remove-all-rows-by-group-if-a-condition-is-met-anywhere-in-the) - but I do not have a variable such as `Count` to filter by.

Comment: Looking back, I do believe `df %>% group_by(name) %>%
  filter(any(year == "2022")) %>% ungroup()` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code

```r
name <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D","D")
year <- c(2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2019,2020,2021,2018,2019,2020,2021)
col <- c(2,1,5,6,7,5,7,3,7,9,1,4)

df <- data.frame(name,year,col)

# base r
df[name %in% c(df[year==2021,'name']),]


#>    name year col
#> 6     C 2019   5
#> 7     C 2020   7
#> 8     C 2021   3
#> 9     D 2018   7
#> 10    D 2019   9
#> 11    D 2020   1
#> 12    D 2021   4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If we are working with a data.frame or `tibble`, we can use `dplyr::filter` on a data.frame grouped `.by` the `name` variable. I changed the data into a proper tibble beforehand.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(name, year, col)

df |> 
    filter(2021 %in% year,
           .by = name)

# A tibble: 7 × 3
  name   year   col
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 C      2019     5
2 C      2020     7
3 C      2021     3
4 D      2018     7
5 D      2019     9
6 D      2020     1
7 D      2021     4
```